# Remapping keys for web-browing use

Tags: cross-browser

I would like to find a way to create keyboard shortcuts/button mappings for web browsing. I would like to:

1. Close tabs via button click -- I want to be able to close tabs quickly without having to click the close button.
2. Switch between tabs --  If there is a way to specify, either by dedicated buttons or hotkey, I would like to switch between tabs using only a mouse button press or by mapping it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

I use a Logitech mouse with multiple buttons built in, so I am looking for a solution that could be implemented on it.

Comment: Ctrl-W works in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.  That probably does what you need.

Comment: Tabs in what application?

Comment: There are already keyboard shortcuts for these functions in most major browsers. Your question isn't about "cross-browser" so please edit it to make the tags more appropriate. You also need to specify the OS. Further, Logitech mice probably support macros and you could program these to do what you want and yet you haven't told us anything you've tried already or what you've researched. This question should not be reopened until you've "shown your homework" as it were.

Comment: Have you looked at Logitech's own software for this? Depending on which product you own, some are capable of being remapped in the LT control panel.